Are questions about the articulation of cryptographic concepts and methods in software development on topic?
I've been asking some application-related questions recently:

is-a-random-length-extension-worth-the-effort
tips-on-conceiving-safe-software-messaging-platform

And I wonder if software application related questions (or how cryptographic concepts are used throughout an application's architecture) are on topic on this stackexhange, as most other questions around here relate to the more theoretical aspects of the matter.
I'd like to continue with some other practical questions, and I'd like to be able to formulate them here rather then on stackoverflow for example, as the specific mindset suits my project more. I'd rather have a sharp rebuttal from a cryptologist then a "should be good enough" from a fellow programmer. I don't mind being flooded with formulas and attack-vectors either.
